# Format .Net date with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm currently trying to format dates i have in a "list". At the end i should get 
06.11.2015. 14:51
02.11.2015. 13:56
06.11.2015. 14:51
02.11.2015. 13:56

but i get 
02.11.2015. 13:56
02.11.2015. 13:56
02.11.2015. 13:56
02.11.2015. 13:56

I don't want same date for each elements. I'm not getting what is wrong in my code.
Here's an overview to make it more clear : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbz5mLdv/)

Thanks a lot for your help !!

```
<html>
     <head>
     <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
     <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var date = $('.start-date').text();
            var strArray = date.match(/(\d+)/g);
            var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) 
            {
                var d = parseInt(strArray[i]);
                var dateF =  new Date (d);
                var dd = dateF.getDate();
                var mm = dateF.getMonth() + 1;
                var yyyy = dateF.getFullYear();
                var hh = dateF.getHours();
                var mn = dateF.getMinutes();
                if(dd<10){
                dd = '0' + dd
                } 
                if(mm<10){
                mm='0'+mm
                } 
                var today = dd+'.'+mm+'.'+yyyy+'. '+hh+':'+mn;
                console.log(today);


                $( ".start-date" ).each(function( index ) {
                  $( this ).text(today);
                });
            };
    });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="start-date">/Date(1446817860000)/</div>

<div class="start-date">/Date(1446468960000)/</div>

<div class="start-date">/Date(1446817860000)/</div>

<div class="start-date">/Date(1446468960000)/</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code simply gets all the date strings concatenated together, then applies the result to that long string.

Your code belongs inside the `each` loop!

e.g. something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".start-date").each(function (index) {
        var date = $(this).text();
        var strArray = date.match(/(\d+)/g);
        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
            var d = parseInt(strArray[i]);
            var dateF = new Date(d);
            var dd = dateF.getDate();
            var mm = dateF.getMonth() + 1;
            var yyyy = dateF.getFullYear();
            var hh = dateF.getHours();
            var mn = dateF.getMinutes();
            if (dd < 10) {
                dd = '0' + dd
            }
            if (mm < 10) {
                mm = '0' + mm
            }
            var today = dd + '.' + mm + '.' + yyyy + '. ' + hh + ':' + mn;
            console.log(today);

            $(this).text(today);
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: _"Your code simply gets the first date"_ That's wrong. `$('.start-date').text()` returns the concatenated text of all matched elements. That's why the fiddle shows the **last** date

Comment: @Andreas: You'd think after 2 years of writing jQuery plugins I would have come across that before. Have corrected the comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to update each div on every iteration, just needed one.
http://jsfiddle.net/wbz5mLdv/1/

Change:

```
$( ".start-date" ).each(function( index ) {
    $( this ).text(today);
});
```

To:

```
$(".start-date").eq(i).text(today);
```